# Magento 2 store view same product with different stock levels

Tags: magento2, store-view, inventory, manage-stock

I have set up 2 stores views eg. uk/us  both have exactly same structure of categories same products etc... except for the stock qty levels. I've been playing around and I know for fact I can disabled the product for a specific store view and change description,name,sku etc... except qty per store view.

I am little bit confused what is possible and what is not is this is possible out of the box or it will need an extension or any other ideas how can one achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not available in M2out of the box. 
Something like this is in the works on [GitHub](https://github.com/magento-engcom/msi) but for now you will probably need a module.